# Equivalent of "-less"

Tags: derivation, negation

Given a Latin noun, how does one transform it into an adjective meaning "lacking [noun]" (the equivalent of English "-less")?  I know that "having (a lot of) [noun]" would be formed with the ending "-ōsus"; what is its opposite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latin seems to be far less uniform in this than English.
Unfortunately there is no single way to derive adjectives indicating a lack.
Here are some possible ways:

- Someone without *cura* is *securus*, but the prefix *se-* is quite rare in this use.
- As Cerberus mentions, *in-* is more common, as in *infamis* has no *fama*.
- Someone without *forma* is *deformis*, and *de-* seems to be more productive than *se-* and I get the impression that it is more common than *in-*.

  In particular, if you want a word for someone who used to have something but no longer has, the combination of *de-* and *-atus* is a good option.
  For example, *decoloratus* would be "discolored" (as opposed to *coloratus*, "colored") and most would understand that *debarbatus* has had their beard shaven off.

There are several possible prefixes, and they are sometimes combined with suffixes.
In some cases several prefixes reach the same goal: *demens* and *amens* are roughly the same.
There seems to be no *semens* or *immens*, and the latter would be easily confused with *immensus*.

Answer (score 4):

It probably depends on the noun, but the normal negative/privative affix is *in-*, which is related to English *un-*, Greek *a(n)-* (the alpha privans), and all/most Indo-European negations with nasal sounds (Latin *non*, English *no* etc.). Then you add any of the semantically week adjectival suffixes such as *-us, -osus, -is, -lis, etc*. Examples:

> *dolor - indolorosus/indoloris* "painless"
>
> *cura - incuriosus* "careless"
>
> *anima - inanimalis/inanimus/inanimis* "breathless, soulless"

Note that it is not always easy to establish whether a word is derived from a substantive, adjective or verbal stem, since all are often similar or the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how Latin works. Use carēre + abl. if you need a verb, or vacuus/plenus + abl./gen. if you want to modify a noun: “itaque cum sumus necessariis negotiis curisque vacui...” (De Oficiis, I.13)

Comment: Welcome to the site! The opposite can be easily expressed in Latin (*barbatus* or *ensifer* or other constructions), and as the other answers show, also lack can be expressed with an adjective like this. It's certainly trickier than in English, but not utterly impossible. However, you are right that this kind of thing is typically expressed in other ways in Latin.

Comment: This answer makes a good point. I'd add that the word _sine_ can sometimes be a better way to express the idea.